# MySQL: Regular expression that matches these criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I need a regular expression in MySQL that matches:

- a sentence that has a word
- that begins with e
- ends with k
- can contain [deki] (doesn't have to include all)
- is 3-4 characters long

For example, the following would match:

- "My name is **eik**"
- "the **edik** of doom"
- "herp derp **eidk** derp"

Comment: do you mind me asking, out of curiousity, why? Seems a strange pattern to match...

Comment: @Chimoo I'm not going to go into a lot of details of exactly what I'm making but I'm creating a simple system that allows you to search for a word that matches user-defined criteria. The user can define the letters allowed, beginning letter, end letter, and word length range. I used the example above for specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's extended regular expressions are pretty powerful; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html. You can write:

```
[[:<:]]e[deki]{1,2}k[[:>:]]
```

(boundary-at-start-of-word, plus `e`, plus one or two characters from `[deki]`, plus `k`, plus boundary-at-end-of-word).

This assumes that your words are separated by punctuation or spaces or whatnot, and it doesn't require that your field contain multiple words.

(Hat-tip to [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) for giving an answer that used `\b`. MySQL doesn't support `\b` for word-boundaries, but it reminded me of things my original answer missed.)

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried it before you edited it and was wondering what could be done about word boundaries then you edited with what I needed to know.

Comment: would you happen to know the PHP equivalent of this?e.g.
    if (preg_match($regexp, "eidk"))
In this case, just comparing one word, not a sentence

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response!!

Comment: I've got another problem now. If I did [[:<:]]d[deki]{1,10}d[[:>:]] I'd expect "Many a good deed was done" to match, but it doesn't. It seems it matches each character only once. How do I make it so it doesn't matter how many times a letter is used so the word "deed" matches the query?

Comment: @HexelC: I don't know if you've made a copy-and-paste error, or if you're using a different version of MySQL, or what, but I just tried `SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE 'Many a good deed was done' REGEXP '[[:<:]]d[deki]{1,10}d[[:>:]]';` on MySQL 5.1.53, and it returned `1`.

Comment: Aw, there was no problem with the query. Problem with PHP, never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE column RLIKE '[[:<:]]e[deki]{1,2}k[[:>:]]'
```

#### Edited:

mysql doesn't support `\b`, instead it uses `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` for start and end of word respectively. regex updated accordingly

Comment: You raise good points, and `\b` would be a good move if MySQL supported it, but even in a regex engine that *did* support it, your regex could never match any string, because it requires a word-boundary between `k` and `e`.